# How to combine beans with the same type into an array by using annotations only?

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I have several beans:

```
@Bean
public MyBean myBean1(){
    return new MyBean(1);
}

@Bean
public MyBean myBean2(){
    return new MyBean(2);
}

@Bean
public MyBean myBean3(){
    return new MyBean(3);
}
```

I would like to combine them into one collection and pass as an argument.
Something like:

```
@Bean
public MyFinalBean myFinalBean(Collection<MyBean> myBeans){
    return new MyFinalBean(myBeans);
}
```

Is there a possibility to combine beans with annotations only? I.e. without using a separate method with `applicationContext.getBeansOfType(MyBean.class);`?

Comment: 3 beans of `MyBean ` , are they of same class or different class? I just want to make sure you're not creating three beans of same kind without explicit name

Comment: They all of the same class. I am using Spring 5. Not sure about other versions, but in this version each Bean has a name of its method. I.e. it's not required to use @Bean(name = "myBean1").

Comment: Ya I know spring will use method name to name the bean, but we should explicit set the name for better debuging

Comment: Yes, totally agree with you. But I think that it is unnecessary information for this question. That is why I omitted bean names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring is able to autowire all beans implementing the same interface into one collection of that interface. The following code works correctly:

```
@Bean
public MyFinalBean myObject(List<MyBean> lst) {
    return new MyFinalBean(lst);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I just didn't know it. It's what I need.